# How to restore accidentlly deleted `/var` folder in Ubuntu installation?

Tags: ubuntu

I accidentlly deleted `/var` folder form my ubuntu istalltion. Can it be restored somehow, without loosing the installation? Please suggest what options I do have?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what backups are for?

Answer (score 2):

`/var` contains some important folders which hold the state for programs (in `/var/lib`). Your program state (dpkg) has gone too, so you will end up with a reinstallation of programs anyway.

Since `/var/log` has gone too, you cannot analyse `/var/log/apt/history.log` either so you have to rely on your memory to know which programs you've installed. After restoring the dpkg and packages database (probably by `sudo install -D -m755 /var/lib/dpkg && sudo apt-get update`), you can use `dpkg -S /path/to/file` to get the package for a given path.

That said, a reinstallation would be the easiest way. Make a backup of `/home` (and possibly `/etc` if you changed system-wide settings or users/groups) and do a reinstall. If your `/home` was on a separate partition, it's even easier: mark that partition as `/home` in the installer, but do not tick "format".

Comment: I don't understand: if he lost `/var`, how can he look at `/var/log/apt/history.log`?

Comment: @Lohoris: well, that's technically possible since `/var/log` could be a separate mount point. Updated answer with for a more likely situation.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but...
This problem happened to me yesterday and I found this [ubuntu forum topic](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1085517), it was very usefull.

I accidentally erased my `/var folder`... sudo nautilus, is not a good idea... Ooops, my fault.

I just created an Ubuntu VM (same version)  in other computer, I copied the `/var folder` from this clean installation and paste it in the computer (HDD) where I erased the /`var folder`.

There are a couple of things that happened to me, maybe of interest:

I was able to start ubuntu without the `/var folder`, but there was not GUI (Unity/Gnome); I could only use the console (Like when you press ctrl+alt F1 or something like that) and for some reason the flash drives were not recognized.

From the ubuntu's LiveCD the flashdrives were readable (and writable). So my solution was to open a terminal and using "sudo cp" to copy the "clean /var directory" into the computer that was missing the /var folder

Now I am available to start ubuntu "normally" and even run every program, like GGTS (an eclipse derived), pgAdmin, firefox... except tomcat
Everything seems to work as before erasing the /var folder, but I plan to reinstall Ubuntu in the moment I can, just to be sure.

NOTE: The harddrive when booting from livecd is in /media/

I was using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

You probably deleted it from your *file browser* while in *root* mode. The files don't actually get deleted. It gets moved to the *root* user *trash*.
I found mine in `root/.local/share/.Trash`.

It's not always the same folder. You will have to look. I deleted my `var` folder twice! Once intentionally, I wanted to do a reinstall and save some folder as is. I deleted my `var` folder and, after reinstall, I realized my local site folders where there.

I had backup so was not worried, but when I look,  the space used was very high for a new install. What helped me find it was the disk usage application `baobab` run in `sudo` mode.